# Set <div> height based on font size?

Tags: html, css

I have a Java application that displays a single HTML file within a WebView.

The following CSS snippet is used to set the style of a `<div>` in that web page:

```
.header {
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #0479ccff;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

However, the font size of the text within the `<div>` is adjustable by the application user so I need to have a way to scale the height of the div relative to the font size. With larger fonts, the `<div>` height remains the same and the text overlaps its bottom border.

Is there a way to do with with pure CSS?

Comment: It seems the size of the content can determine the height of `.header`, [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/rng2u3mo/1/). Is that what you mean?

Comment: It might help if you create a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help demonstrate. What sort of element is `.header`?

Comment: How does this relate to Java?

Comment: yeah it doesn't.... really the tag but .

Comment: I tagged it as Java because it's using the Java WebEngine (as mentioned in the question) and perhaps it behaves differently than expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That **height: 20px** is preventing your div from growing.  Instead of height, try using **min-height** instead.

```
.header {
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #0479cc;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 5px;
    min-height: 20px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

This would keep the height by at least 20px, while allowing the div to grow to accommodate the increase in font size.

---

***Sample Demo***

Adding a demo to increase/decrease font size, using JavaScript to change the .header font-size.  It looks like you can click on Run Snippet to see the demo.

```js
var gFontSize = 16;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#grow').click(function() {
    $(".header").css("font-size", ++gFontSize);
  });

  $('#shrink').click(function() {
    $(".header").css("font-size", --gFontSize);
  });
});
```

```css
.header {
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #0479cc;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 5px;
  min-height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>test</title>
</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="header">TEXT</div>
  <button id="grow">increase font</button>
  <button id="shrink">decrease font</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Specify the height in `em` instead of in pixels. Then, as the font size changes, the height will automatically change .

```
.header {
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #0479ccff;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 1.8em;
}
```

Comment: I also often use `em` units to keep elements proportional regardless of font size. However, in this context, it seems that larger fonts might wrap to more lines than smaller ones. This could affect the required height as well, but will not be addressed by using `em` units. [Example here](https://jsfiddle.net/omLyr6cn/).

Answer (score 0):

Sure. If you get rid of the height, and then the height of the div should change with the text.

Do this:

```
.header {
margin: auto;
background-color: #0479ccff;
font-weight: bold;
color: #FFFFFF;
padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: This does not scale with the text, though. I end up with a very thin <div> and the text just flows right over the top of it.

Comment: @Zephyr Please show a demo of the issue. That does not sound like default behavior. Is the content floated or positioned absolutely?